# Integrate phpmd in windows IDE

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpmd

I'm looking for an executable phpMD file for integration with PHPStorm on windows. 
The phpmd website has instructions for installing / building via git, but is there an executable .exe / bat file?

Can someone give a hint where to find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have composer :

```
composer global require phpmd/phpmd
```

Then the .bat is available in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Comment: Thanks, this is still useful in 2020.